# How does one, from an array of objects, collect and aggregate the merged variant of all objects with a specific equal property value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, grouping, reduce

```
const portfolio = [
  { name: 'Mark', stock: 'FB' },
  { name: 'Steve', stock: 'AAPL' },
  { name: 'Tim', stock: 'AAPL' },
  { name: 'Steve', stock: 'MSFT' },
  { name: 'Bill', stock: 'MSFT' },
  { name: 'Bill', stock: 'AAPL' },
];

// Output
const shareholder = [
  { stock: 'AAPL', name: ['Steve', 'Bill', 'Tim'], count: 3 },
  { stock: 'MSFT', name: ['Steve', 'Bill'], count: 2 },
  { stock: 'FB', name: ['Mark'], count: 1 },
];
```

if I create one function which take input array as param and this will return output array in jS

Comment: What the OP wants is filtering and grouping array items (by a specific `key`) together with value aggregation of some/one other key/s. One usually would use a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach. One question though ... what is the additional `count` value good for when one has this information already in any item's `item.name.length` (or at least rename `count` to `nameCount`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I group an array of objects by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-can-i-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)  Not only a duplicate, but a duplicate that accounts for 80 percent of the JavaScript questions.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `reduce` and `Object.values`

```js
const portfolio = [{
    name: 'Mark',
    stock: 'FB'
  },
  {
    name: 'Steve',
    stock: 'AAPL'
  },
  {
    name: 'Tim',
    stock: 'AAPL'
  },
  {
    name: 'Steve',
    stock: 'MSFT'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bill',
    stock: 'MSFT'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bill',
    stock: 'AAPL'
  },
];

const result = Object.values(portfolio.reduce((res, {
  stock,
  name
}) => {
  const existing = res[stock] || {
    stock,
    names: [],
    count: 0
  }
  res[stock] = {
    stock,
    names: [...existing.names, name],
    count: existing.count + 1
  }
  return res
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the above comment ...

> *"What the OP wants is filtering and grouping array items (by a specific `key`) together with value aggregation of some/one other key/s. One usually would use a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach. One question though ... what is the additional `count` value good for when one has this information already in any item's `item.name.length` (or at least rename `count` to `nameCount`)."*

... used techniques/methods ...

- [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
- [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [Destructuring Assignment / object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)
- [Logical nullish assignment operator / `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

```js
const portfolio = [
  { name: 'Mark', stock: 'FB' },
  { name: 'Steve', stock: 'AAPL' },
  { name: 'Tim', stock: 'AAPL' },
  { name: 'Steve', stock: 'MSFT' },
  { name: 'Bill', stock: 'MSFT' },
  { name: 'Bill', stock: 'AAPL' },
];
const shareholderList = Object.values( // get only the values from ...

  // ... create an index/map of stock specific shareholder items/objects
  portfolio.reduce((stockIndex, { name, stock }) => {

    // access an already existing object or
    // create a new grouped (by `stock` value) to be merged and aggregated object.
    const groupedMerger = (stockIndex[stock] ??= { stock, names: [], nameCount: 0 });

    // aggregate list of `stock` specific shareholder names.
    groupedMerger.names.push(name);
    // increment count of `stock` specific shareholder names.
    ++groupedMerger.nameCount;

    // the programmatically built index/map of stock specific shareholder items/objects.
    return stockIndex;
  }, {})

).sort((a, b) => b.nameCount - a.nameCount); // sort shareholder items by theirs `nameCount`s.

console.log({ shareholderList });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

And in order to demonstrate how each part works and how everything works together, the above main approach will be compacted into a (re-usable) [function statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function).

```js
function aggregateStockIndex(index, { name, stock }) {
  const groupedMerger = (index[stock] ??= { stock, names: [], nameCount: 0 });

  groupedMerger.names.push(name);
  ++groupedMerger.nameCount;

  return index;
}

const portfolio = [
  { name: 'Mark', stock: 'FB' },
  { name: 'Steve', stock: 'AAPL' },
  { name: 'Tim', stock: 'AAPL' },
  { name: 'Steve', stock: 'MSFT' },
  { name: 'Bill', stock: 'MSFT' },
  { name: 'Bill', stock: 'AAPL' },
];
const stockIndex = portfolio
  .reduce(aggregateStockIndex, {});

const shareholderList = Object.values(

  // stockIndex
  portfolio.reduce(aggregateStockIndex, {})

).sort((a, b) => b.nameCount - a.nameCount);


console.log({
  stockIndex,
  shareholderList,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: For noobs like me: Using [`??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) within the assignment achieves two objectives here. It assigns the object `{stock, name: [], ....}` to `stockIndex[stock]` iff the latter is nullish. And, in either case, the `groupedMerger` variable is populated with the object (either pre-existing in `stockIndex[stock]`, or assigned using `??=`). It's so little code to do so many things. Happy that I'm learning JS. :-) If I've mis-stated, please enlighten.

Answer (score 0):

I shared a function named `groupPortfolio` that takes a portfolio as an argument expecting to be a list of people holding a share of a stock.

The function first groups those people as a map binding each stock to which holders it belong to and eventually uses that map to create the final array as a list of stocks where each one has a list of people holding its share and the corresponding amount of people in that list.

```js
function groupPortfolio(portfolio){

  //groups the portfolio item in [stock] => shareholders[]
  let grouped = {};
  for(let o of portfolio){
    if( !Object.keys(grouped).includes(o.stock) )
      grouped[o.stock] = [];
    grouped[o.stock].push( o.name );
  }
  
  //creates the shareholders array starting from the grouped stocks
  let shareholders = [];
  for( let stockGroup of Object.keys(grouped) ){
    shareholders.push(
      { stock: stockGroup, name: grouped[stockGroup], count: grouped[stockGroup].length }
    );
  }

  return shareholders;  
}

const portfolio1 = [
  {name: 'Mark', stock: 'FB'},
  {name: 'Steve', stock: 'AAPL'},
  {name: 'Tim', stock: 'AAPL'},
  {name: 'Steve', stock: 'MSFT'},
  {name: 'Bill', stock: 'MSFT'},
  {name: 'Bill', stock: 'AAPL'},
];

let shareholder1 = groupPortfolio(portfolio1);
console.log( shareholder1 );
/*
0:
  stock: "FB"
  name: ['Mark']
  count: 1
1:
  stock: "AAPL"
  name: (3) ['Steve', 'Tim', 'Bill']
  count: 3
2:
  stock: "MSFT"
  name: (2) ['Steve', 'Bill']
  count: 2
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two simple `for loops` to convert the first `array` into the second `array`.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const portfolio = [
  {name: 'Mark', stock: 'FB'},
  {name: 'Steve', stock: 'AAPL'},
  {name: 'Tim', stock: 'AAPL'},
  {name: 'Steve', stock: 'MSFT'},
  {name: 'Bill', stock: 'MSFT'},
  {name: 'Bill', stock: 'AAPL'},
];

let shareholder = [];

// CYCLE THROUGH PORTFOLIO
for (let i = 0; i < portfolio.length; i++) {
  
  // DETERMINE IF STOCK ENTRY ALREADY EXISTS
  let stockIndex = shareholder.length;

  for (let j = 0; j < shareholder.length; j++) {
  
    if (portfolio[i].stock === shareholder[j].stock) {
    
      stockIndex = j;
    }
  }
  
  // ADD NEW ENTRY IF STOCK ENTRY DOES NOT EXIST
  if (stockIndex === shareholder.length) {
  
    shareholder[stockIndex] = {stock: portfolio[i].stock, name: [], count: 0};
  }
  
  // ADD DETAILS TO NEW OR EXISTING STOCK ENTRY
  shareholder[stockIndex].name.push(portfolio[i].name);
  shareholder[stockIndex].count++;
}

console.log(shareholder);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this in two steps

1. First create an object with `stock` as the key name to find out all the records with unique stock.
2. Loop over the object created in step#1 to convert to an Array structure

I couldn't think of ay solution which could achieve it in single iteration.

Please see the code snippet below.

```js
const portfolio = [
{name: 'Mark', stock: 'FB'},
{name: 'Steve', stock: 'AAPL'},
{name: 'Tim', stock: 'AAPL'},
{name: 'Steve', stock: 'MSFT'},
{name: 'Bill', stock: 'MSFT'},
{name: 'Bill', stock: 'AAPL'},
];

let shareholderObj = {};
let shareholderArr = [];

portfolio.forEach((el) => {
  const stock = el.stock
  if(shareholderObj[stock]){
    shareholderObj[stock].name.push(el.name)
  }
  else{
    shareholderObj[stock] = {
      name: [el.name]
    }
  }
})

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(shareholderObj)) {
    shareholderArr.push({
      stock: key,
      name: value.name,
      count: value.name.length
    })
}

console.log(shareholderArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplified approach by taking the new length of `name` as `count`.

```js
const portfolio = [{ name: 'Mark', stock: 'FB' }, { name: 'Steve', stock: 'AAPL' }, { name: 'Tim', stock: 'AAPL' }, { name: 'Steve', stock: 'MSFT' }, { name: 'Bill', stock: 'MSFT' }, { name: 'Bill', stock: 'AAPL' }],
    shareholder = Object
        .values(portfolio.reduce((r, { name, stock }) => {
            r[stock] ??= { stock, name: [] };
            r[stock].count = r[stock].name.push(name);
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count)

console.log(shareholder);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```